# libGdx and obtuse SensorManager errors in LogCat

Tags: android, libgdx, android-sensors

I use libGDX for a 2D application. The application runs fine except there are two errors in LogCat:

```
04-07 15:19:59.579: E/SensorManager(5326): ***[disableSensorLocked]name = ADXL346 Acceleration Sensor
04-07 15:19:59.579: E/SensorManager(5326): res = true
04-07 15:19:59.579: E/SensorManager(5326): ***[disableSensorLocked]name = MS-3C (YAS529) Magnetic Sensor
04-07 15:19:59.579: E/SensorManager(5326): res = true
```

I don't instantiate `SensorManager` directly and don't use it in my libGDX project. What's wrong?

I see no such error messages on the emulator, only on a real device (Acer Liquid). What do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libgdx will enable many sensors by default.  You can explicitly disable the ones you don't want by setting some flags in the [`AndroidApplicationConfiguration`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html) that gets passed to [`AndroidApplication.initialize()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.html#initialize%28com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener,%20com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration%29).

Like this:

```
appListener = ...
// Configure libGDX app options:
AndroidApplicationConfiguration appCfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
appCfg.useAccelerometer = false;
appCfg.useCompass = false;
... other appCfg options ...

initialize(appListener, appCfg);
```

Comment: Mario (the author of libGDX) answered my question on Badlogic forum - it's driver issue specific to my phone. Doesn't affect anything. +1 for advice to disable unused features.